# Calling a member Function (size) of a Referenced Vector Throwing Error

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to pass a vector to a function (printGrid) and have it print out the size of the vector. The vector is being passed by reference. When I try to compile, I get the error:

```
std::vector<char,std::allocator<char>>::size': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

This is the relevant part of the program in question:

```
void printGrid(const std::vector<char>& grid, int width) { 
    std::cout << grid.size;
}

int main() {

    int width, height;
    std::cin >> width >> height;

    std::vector<char> grid = getGrid(width, height);

    printGrid(grid, width);

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put parentheses after the `size` function, e.g.:

```
cout << grid.size();
```

Otherwise the compiler thinks you're trying to access a member variable named "size" instead of the member function of the same name.

Comment: The compiler error *is* pretty useless in this case.

Comment: Yes, that was why I was so confused, I kept looking for errors in how I implemented the vector reference.